# Bringing a list of remaining items from list using REGEXMATCH - problem with + sign

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a list of email addresses ("All emails"), I have a second list of emails that I've contacted  ("Contacted") and I want to create a third list of the ones who exist on the first list but not on the second ("To contact").
I use REGEXMATCH to bring the list of remaining email and it works great:

*=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(A2:A,NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,B2:B)))))*

The problem is that emails that contain the + sign aren't recognized as used and are added to the "To contact" list although they appear in the "Contacted" list.

For example, john@email.com will not be brought to the third list (as expected), but john+2@email.com will be added to the list although he was actually contacted.

Here's an example, Col A is "All emails" Col B is "Contacted" Col C is "To contact" and I marked the problematic emails yellow:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fesr5tjjMhruP1otVHfQXvwYtmbz2nhT4THjZulHNfw/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape special regex metacharacters:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(A2:A,NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "([[+$^*()\\{?.|])", "\\$1"))))))
```

With `REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "([[+$^*()\\{?.|])", "\\$1")`, you match and capture `[`, `+`, `$`, `^`, `*`, `(`, `)`, `\`, `{`, `?`, `.` and `|` with a backslash and they are matched as literal chars.

To find out what chars are special in RE2 regex flavor, see the [RE2 regex library documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Technincally, `([[+$^*()\\{?.|])` is a regular expression that matches *and captures* into Group 1 a single char from the specified set as `(...)` defines a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). The [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) command I used above replaces every found match with `\\$1`, i.e. a literal backslash and the value of Group 1. Namely, this means we prepend each found match with a single literal backslash. The backslash in the replacement pattern must be doubled as it is a special char even in the replacement pattern (it can escape the `$` char if you need to use it as a literal char in the replacement pattern).

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Any good source you know where I can read about the escape you did? I understand the login but not how to technically do it. Also, what is the "\\$1" at the end?

Comment: @Tom I added some more explanations. `$1` is a placeholder referring to Group 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a function to substitute the '+' symbol for another not being used as a special character with RegExmatch
.